¿Cómo puedo mostrar en pantalla e resultado de esta función lambda?
Recientemente comencé a ver el tema de lambdas en Java y me han dejado varios ejercicios de tarea pero no entiendo muy bien como funciona. Para mi tarea debo reescribir este código para que ahora sea capaz de ordenar los arreglos de manera descendente. pero ni siquiera se como mostrar en pantalla cuando los ordena de manera ascendente. La ultima línea la agregue yo pero muestra referencias de memoria no el contenido de los arreglos.
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] array1 = {"Donusa", "Galápagos", "Hawái"};

        String[] array2 = {"I", "really", "love", "cookies"};

        String[] array3 = {"if", "then", "else"};


        List<String[]> arrays = new ArrayList<>();

        arrays.add(array1);

        arrays.add(array2);

        arrays.add(array3);

        arrays.sort(new Comparator<String[]>() {

            @Override

            public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {

                return o1.length - o2.length;
            }
        });
        arrays.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

Este ese el resultado que muestra en pantalla:
[Ljava.lang.String;@3b07d329
[Ljava.lang.String;@41629346
[Ljava.lang.String;@404b9385


Se soluciona con un toString()

Debes acceder al contenido de la lista y luego al contenido de los arrays que guardan las palabras... arrays.forEach(n->Arrays.stream(n).forEach(System.out::println));

El problema, es que estás manejando dos tipos distintos de arreglos, porque tenés una lista que contiene tres arrays.
Hay varias formas de mostrarlas:
for( int i = 0; i < arrays.size(); i++ ) {
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString( arrays.get( i ) ));         
} 

El for va recorriendo la lista, y el Arrays.toString() muestra el contenido de los arrays contenidos.
for( String arr[] : arrays ) {
   System.out.println( Arrays.toString( arr ) );
}

Lo mismo pero con un foreach.
for( int i = 0; i < arrays.size(); i ++ ) {
   for( int k = 0; k < arrays.get( i ).length; k ++ ) {
      System.out.println( arrays.get( i )[ k ] ); 
   }        
} 

En este otro, el for externo sigue recorriendo la lista, el interno toma el tamaño de cada array contenido en la lista y lo usa como límite de iteración, y dentro del cuerpo le pide a la lista el array y a este un item, que sería lo mismo que usar:
for( int i = 0; i < arrays.size(); i ++ ) {
   String arr[] = arrays.get( i );
   for( int k = 0; k < arr.length; k ++ ) {
      System.out.println( arr[ k ] ); 
   }        
} 

Acá creamos un nuevo array después del primer for y le asignamos los contenidos en la lista.
for( String arr[] : arrays ) {
   for( String str : arr ) {
      System.out.println( str );
   }
}

Y por último, doble foreach.
Espero haberte aclarado un poco el tema.
PD: dado que estás trabajndo con arrays y con listas, es un poco desafortunado el uso del nombre arrays para la lista, creo que seía más claro, algo como listaDeArrays o algo así.
Editando, creo poder asegurar, que no hay forma de mostrar ni arrays ni listas con lambdas (aunque puede fallar), así que supongo que lo que te deben haber pedido, es que realices la ordenación con ellas, te dejo el código correspondiente:
public void ordenaListaS( List <String> lista ) {
   lista.sort( ( a, b ) -> a[ 0 ].compareTo( b[ 0 ] ) );
   for( String arr[]: lista ) {
      Arrays.sort( arr, ( x, y ) -> x.compareTo( y ) );
   }
}

No se si se puede hacer en una sola línea, estoy probando, si encuentro como, edito.

lo que quiero saber es como mostrar el resultado en pantalla pero usando lambdas, es lo que me piden en la terea. De cualquier forma gracias por la respuesta  (tendré en cuenta como poner las etiquetas la próxima vez)

Hola Victor, edite mi respuesta, para adaptarla a tus comentarios (bueno, a lo que yo interpreto de ellos).

Muchas gracias de verdad, no sabes cuanto agradezco la amabilidad con la que contestan todas mis dudas aqui, me hace perder el miedo a preguntar y el miedo a no entender un tema nuevo

Maestro, me alegra mucho haberte ayudado.
